# Windows Defender cannot seem to remove an identified trojan from the threat list

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

About a week ago, I got an alert from Windows Defender stating that I had a trojan in my user folder, after investigating it for a bit, I realized it was a false positive, but nontheless I decided to quarantine it and remove the folder containing entirely.

Back to today, the same trojan appeared, with the same folder (which is deleted, it didn't appear back), and when I try to quarantine it, Defender seems to completely ignore it and keep it as an active alert.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt3MU.png]

Comment: This reads like a FYI, not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I realized it was a false positive, but nonetheless I decided to
> quarantine it

If it is truly a false positive (I do see these), then Whitelist the item.  Windows Defender, Virus and Threat protection, Current Threats, Allowed Threats.

Once Whitelisted, exit Windows Defender, restart the computer and test.

Continuing to Quarantine will not help. Whitelisting is the solution.

You can always delete the item if you do not want it.